# How to read your own facebook inbox using python sdk?

Tags: facebook, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.1

Can someone suggest how to read the facebook messages using the python SDK with Graph API's.

I know how to read messages from pages.But i want to know how to read messages from my account itself

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible any more.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations:

> 90-day deprecations (effective Tuesday, October 6, 2015)
>
> The `GET /v2.4/{user_id}/home`, `GET /v2.4/{user_id}/inbox`, and `GET /v2.4/{user_id}/notifications` operations as well as `read_stream`, `read_mailbox`, and `manage_notifications` permissions are deprecated in v2.4.

Those endpoints and permissions have been removed for all apps on said date; there is no replacement.